# Send commands to the opened python terminal

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, terminal

The goal is to open python terminal with pre-execution of some commands. In real life it's loading some modules and defines some variables, but here is a simplified version:

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

r=Popen("python",creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
r.communicate(input=b"print(2+2)")
```

CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is used, because otherwise terminal window doesn't appear (I run the code from IDE). The code above opens a python terminal window, but input doesn't get there. Trying some variations stops window from appearing, like:

```
r=Popen(["python","print(2+2)"],creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Or

```
r=Popen("python",creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, stdin=PIPE)
r.communicate(input=b"print(2+2)")
```

So what can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: Well, the second and third examples open and close very quickly. Are you trying to pipe something to stdin but also attached have stdin attached to the terminal?

Comment: If I understand your question right, the main idea is to remotely launch multiple commands to terminal without closing the window. All of above tried to achieve that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494945/createprocess-with-new-console-window-but-override-some-std-i-o-handles

Comment: I can't even get `C:/msys64/usr/bin/cat.exe` to copy its stdin to the console by using Popen in this way. I strongly suspect that the question I linked is related.

Comment: Does that mean the STARTUPINFO could be changed somehow to accept input from communicate method? Anyway, fortunately the accepted answer does what I want in a simpler way.

Comment: Probably the problem stemmed from trying to have both console and original program as input channels. I'm not sure whether you can do that at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what the environmental variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` is for...

see: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP

[image]

another option would be to use the `-c` `-i` switches

```
C:\>python -i -c "x = 2+2;y=3+3"
>>> x
4
>>> y
6
>>>
```